# creating your own div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to `JavaScript` and `jQuery` and I have this code:

```
 $("input[type = submit]").click(function(){
            $("<div/>").html(itemInput.value).appendTo(".div1");
            clearInput();
 })
```

I am wondering if there is a way to "personalize" the "div" in line 2. Like give it a color background or change the font ?

Comment: `$("<div/>").css({ANYTHING}).html(itemInput.value).appendTo(".div1");`

Comment: use createElement and then setAttribute and then appendChild

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("<div><div/>").attr("style", "background-color: lightblue; font-size: 16px;");
```

Comment: This actually works for what I intend it to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could either add a class to it and then change the css in a separate stylesheet, or use the .css method in jQuery:

```
$("input[type = submit]").click(function(){
    $("<div/>").css({
        'background-color': '#BADA55',
        'font-family': 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
    }).html(itemInput.value).appendTo(".div1");
    clearInput();
})
```

Comment: This works.  Thanks. But its not doing what I thought it would do. It is not displaying a new "div" on the screen when pressing the submit button.

Comment: You probably have to stop the default event first [...].click(function(e){e.preventDefault(); [...]})

Answer (score 0):

**Use the jQuery `.css()` method** with the div you want to style.

```
 $("input[type = submit]").click(function(){

    $("<div/>").css({
        'color' : 'white',
        'background-color' : 'black'
    }).html(itemInput.value).appendTo("‌​.div1");
    clearInput();

 })
```

**READ MORE:**

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp

Answer (score 0):

All these answers are doing it programatically - you can always simply pass simple html when creating -

```js
$("input[type = submit]").click(function(){
            $("<div style='color:red;background:blue' class='something'></div>")
               .html(itemInput.value).appendTo(".div1");
            clearInput();
 })
```

Just as a FYI - `<div/>` is not exactly valid - you should be using either plain `<div>` or `<div></div>` - either way, don't go putting depreciated XHTML code in places when you might end up doing it in your source code: HTML5 ignores the trailing slash completely, and it's the tag itself that decides whether it's self closing or not.

Comment: I think $('<div />'); gets converted by jQuery, so it's valid. If I remember that correctly I saw that on the jquery doc (can't find it now, though)

Comment: You're right in that jQuery corrects it (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2 implies that but it's not explicitly stated) - but the operative part is that jQuery corrects it - putting it into your html source is invalid, so it's not a good practice to get into :-)